# DSR-250N Wifi clients can see each other?

Tags: wifi, timeout, d-link

Is there any change you can isolate wifi traffic between the wifi clients for this (DSR-250N) specific router?

I have a **wifi** client (app) that can't open a wifi (ZEBRA printer) port, getting timeouts. When i use a **wired** PC (connected to the DSR-250N) i can open the port without any problems. So it **seems** clients in the same AP/SSID can't see each other.

I don't have access to this router, but i would help me greatly if could point my customer in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is called 'WLAN Partition' on most D-link routers.

Disable 'WLAN Partition', which is probably on the Access Point Configuration page (depends on firmware), and reboot.

The WLAN Partition feature prevents clients on the wireless from talking to each other.